# Replace HREF with what's in between tags (with expressions for emails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, hyperlink

So in a previous question, I was helped out to learn that you can grab what is in between the link tags and place it inside the HREF:

```
$('a').attr('href', function () {
return 'http://' + $(this).text()})
```

However, I need a bit more help: I need to identify when the text between the tags is an email to make it into a mailto: href instead.

I don't have much experience with reg expressions, so any advice & direction would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried searching for an email regex? There are plenty out there.

Comment: Difficult if you don't have http:// or mailto:// in front as an url can (but rarely does) contain the "@" character.

Comment: You can just check if it start with `mailto`: ... you'll be right 99% of the time and the 1% is probably an invalid syntax. Make sure to trim first.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/372239

Comment: To give more context to my scenario: we have a job board site and employers are not properly using out WYSIWYG editor for links, so we're ending up with a lot of emails not having mailto: and a lot of links to their own sites going to #

Answer (score 2):

First you need to check email with Regular expression. Then pass email to that function for testing. If result is true, put "mailto:" at the beginning of href and if result is false, add "http://" at the beginning.

```
 if(checkEmail($('a').text()))
     $('a').attr('href', "mailto:"+$('a').text())
 else
    $('a').attr('href', "http://"+$('a').text());



function checkEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}
```

Comment: Your regex doesn't match `me@localhost` that is a perfectly valid address.

Comment: I think the regex should follow the official RFC 5322 because there are countries that use UTF-8 email addresses. For example: 伊昭傑@郵件.商務 or юзер@екзампл.ком (those are not actual emails, it's just an example)

Comment: I think `me@localhost` is a very special case and is just for testing and no other emails exist in this format. Also `伊昭傑@郵件.商務` is not a valid and international email address. I think the mentioned regex can cover all **valid** email addresses.

Comment: Well, in our use scenario we don't need to worry about every possible scenario such as very special use cases or other countries (it's a North American platform only)